# Export Salesforce dates in a way that Excel Mac can use

Tags: excel, date, excel-formula, salesforce, report

I am exporting reports as XLS files from Salesforce. These reports have dates that I want to be able to manipulate in Excel but... Excel doesn't recognize them as dates.

The format outputted by Salesforce right now is m/d/yyyy (ie: 8/18/2022). When I go in Excel and change the format to date... the data is not recognized as a date.
It seems the only thing that Excel can consume are dates configured as yyyy-mm-dd.

I tried to play with Excel formatting date form with no luck.[Excel doesn't recognize the Salesforce format, or does not propose anything similar to it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOeDX.png)

Is there a setting in Salesforce or in Excel that I need to adjust so that both apps can generate, and digest the same date configs?
I want to run these reports weekly so whatever requires the less Excel gymnastic will be the best solution (Google Docs for instance recognize dates as Salesforce spits them... - but I can't use GDocs at work).

Comment: It can consume `m/d/yyyy` if your local setting are `m/d/yyyy` and not `d/m/yyyy`.  If not when you import you will need to use the import wizard and tell Excel that the date coming in is formatted different than the local settings, so it knows to make the change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use PowerQuery to import the data to Excel.

In PowerQuery change the Column-Type USING LOCAL
Select Date and English (United States)

Voila!
[image]

Comment: This is amazing! I had no idea that functionality existed. The import tool "magically" recognized and transformed all the data in a format that I can manipulate!